# Figuring out parameters

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I need to figure out a parameter to satisfy the following conditions:

$H(\frac{1}{2}, 0) = 0$

$H(1,0) = 1$

$H(0,1) = 0$

$H(1,1) = 1$

for $H(s,t)$.

I have been at it for hours and can not figure out parameters that satisfy all these conditions.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking, but I guess you are trying to find a function $H(s,t)$ that satisfies the properties listed in your question. For example, if $f(0)=0$ and $f(2) = 4$ were given would $f(x) = x^2$ work for you?

Comment: @manthanomen Oh lol, I have never been this "out of scope."

Answer (score 1):

Well a bilinear solution can be given by observing $ H(s,1) = s $ and $ H(s,0) = 2s-1 $ Then $ H(s,t) = ts + (1-t)(2s-1) $